# When light reflects from a medium of lower index of reflection to a medium of higher index of refraction, why does the light undergo a phase shift?

Tags: visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, boundary-conditions

I learned in my physics class that there is a phase shift when light reflects off a low $n$ from a higher $n$, but never got the explanation.